# Solve the equation on the interval $\; 0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi $

Tags: trigonometry

Hey I have two questions for math exchange! Let me list them first and show you what I have tried. By the way one can not use a calculator on the test review!

> Solve the equations on the interval $\; 0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi $:
>
> - $2 \cos^2\theta - 3\cos \theta + 1 = 0 $
> - $\cot \theta = 2 \cos \theta$

---

So for the first one I tried:

\begin{gather}
2 \cos^2\theta - 3\cos \theta + 1 = 0\\
(2\cos^2\theta - 1) \times (3\cos\theta - 1) = 0\\
\begin{aligned}
2 \cos^2 \theta -1 &= 0 &\text{ or }&&  3\cos\theta -1 =0\\
\cos^2\theta &= \dfrac{1}{2} &\text{ or }&&  \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}

After that I just got confused... I can't use a calculator so I do not know what to do next..

So The next problem was even more diffcult:

$$\cot \theta = 2 \cos \theta$$

And then immediately after that I got confused since there are two theta's, and I have absolutely no clue what to do next!

On the anwser key for test review, the correct anwsers are:

- $$2 \cos^2\theta - 3\cos \theta + 1 = 0$$
  Answer:$\qquad\left\{ 0,\;\dfrac{\pi}{3} ,\; \dfrac{5\pi}{3} \right\}$
- $$\cot \theta = 2 \cos \theta$$ 
  Answer : $\qquad\left\{\dfrac{\pi}{6} ,\; \dfrac{\pi}{2},\; \dfrac{5\pi}{6},\;\dfrac{3\pi}{2} \right\}$

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou for reading!

Comment: The factorization you did for the LHS of the first problem is wrong. The correct factorization is $(2\cos\Theta-1)(\cos\Theta-1)$

Comment: How so @learner ?? Did i really mess up on factorazation!?

Comment: Yes, you did. The factorization you did gives a cubic polynomial in terms of $\cos\Theta$ when expanded while the original one is a quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solve $2\cos^2\theta - 3\cos\theta + 1 = 0$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$.

As learner pointed out in the comments, you factored incorrectly.  To split the linear term, we must find two numbers with product $2 \cdot 1 = 2$ and sum $-3$.  They are $-2$ and $-1$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
2\cos^2\theta - 3\cos\theta + 1 & = 0\\
2\cos^2\theta - 2\cos\theta - \cos\theta + 1 & = 0\\
2\cos\theta(\cos\theta - 1) - 1(\cos\theta - 1) & = 0\\
(2\cos\theta - 1)(\cos\theta - 1) & = 0 
\end{align*}
Setting each factor equal to zero yields
\begin{align*}
2\cos\theta - 1 & = 0 & \cos\theta - 1 & = 0\\
2\cos\theta & = 1 & \cos\theta & = 1\\
\cos\theta & = \frac{1}{2} & \cos\theta & = \cos 0\\
\cos\theta & = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
\end{align*}
Consider the diagram below.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_trigonometric_functions]

By symmetry, if $\cos\theta = \cos(-\theta)$.  Since coterminal angles have the same cosine, 
$$\cos\theta = \cos\varphi  \implies \theta = \pm\varphi + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Hence, 
$$\cos\theta = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \implies \theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{3} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
and 
$$\cos\theta = \cos 0 \implies \theta = 0 + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
We want those solutions in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$.
\begin{align*}  
0 & \leq \frac{\pi}{3} + 2n\pi < 2\pi \implies n = 0 \implies \theta = \frac{\pi}{3}\\
0 & \leq -\frac{\pi}{3} + 2n\pi < 2\pi \implies n = 1 \implies \theta = \frac{5\pi}{3}\\
0 & \leq \theta = 0 + 2n\pi < 2\pi \implies n = 0 \implies \theta = 0
\end{align*}
Hence, the solution set is $S = \left\{0, \dfrac{\pi}{3}, \dfrac{5\pi}{3}\right\}$.

> Solve $\cot\theta = 2\cos\theta$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$.

\begin{align*}
\cot\theta & = 2\cos\theta\\
\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta} & = 2\cos\theta\\
\cos\theta & = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
0 & = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta - \cos\theta\\
0 & = \cos\theta(2\sin\theta - 1)
\end{align*}
Setting each factor equal to $0$ yields
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta & = 0 & 2\sin\theta - 1 & = 0\\
\cos\theta & = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) & 2\sin\theta & = 1\\
& & \sin\theta & = \frac{1}{2}\\
& & \sin\theta & = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)
\end{align*}
By the same reasoning as above, 
$$\cos\theta = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \implies \theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi$$
Consider the diagram above.  By symmetry, $\sin\theta = \sin(\pi - \theta)$.  Since coterminal angles have the same sine, 
$$\sin\theta = \sin\varphi \implies \theta = \varphi + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}~\text{or}~\theta = \pi - \varphi + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Hence, 
$$\sin\theta = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) \implies \theta = \frac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}~\text{or}~\theta = \pi - \frac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
We wish to solve the equation in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$.  I leave it to you to determine the values of $n$ such that 
\begin{align*}
0 & \leq \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi < 2\pi\\
0 & \leq -\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi < 2\pi\\
0 & \leq \frac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi < 2\pi\\
0 & \leq \pi - \frac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi < 2\pi
\end{align*}
and the corresponding values of $\theta$.

Comment: On The First one Factoring is Tough! Thanks a lot though! Wish me luck on my test!

Comment: Yeah I know what your did N.F Taussig! But the real question here is, will i apply your method in my test today... or even be applicable? Is it a 100%?

Comment: I explain the method I used to factor in more detail [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419460/a-more-scientific-way-to-factor/1419497#1419497).  You can only factor a quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c$ using this method if there are rational numbers whose product is $ac$ and whose sum is $b$.  Otherwise, you can complete the square or use the Quadratic Formula to solve the equation.  I hope you do well on your test.

Comment: Oh ok i see. So every time ill just seperate them to 4 elements, and solve them like that! I gotcha! Just one more question! For the 2nd question you solved, you did it the same exact way my teacher did it. and i was just asking if there is two $\Theta$'s in the problem do i just make one side equal to zero... and solve that way?

Comment: I set the equation equal to zero, so I could take advantage of the zero product rule $ab = 0 \iff a = 0~\text{or}~b = 0$.  If you are feeling clever, you can also solve the problem the way that Kuifje did (equating two sine functions, then using the symmetry rules I used above).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Taussig! Helped a whole ton on my test! I will be getting the grade soon, and im definitely sure its a very good one! Again thanks a lot for this help, this was the hardest unit of the whole class!

Comment: I got an A! 95%!! Thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 0):

**First question**: let's call $x=\cos\theta$. Then you have a second order equation $2x^2-3x+1=0$. then you would get two solutions in general, $x_1$ and $x_2$ and the final solution will be $\theta=\arccos(x_1)+n\pi$ and $\theta=\arccos(x_2)+n\pi,\;n\in\mathbb{N}$

**Second question**, use the definition of $\cot\theta=\cos\theta/\sin\theta$. Then, the equation reads
$$\cos\theta\left(\frac{1}{\sin \theta}-2\right)=0$$
Then or $\cos\theta=0$, so $\theta=\pi/2+n\pi,\;n\in\mathbb{N}$ or $\frac{1}{\sin \theta}-2$, which leads to $\sin\theta=1/2$, or equivalently, $\theta=\pi/6+n\pi,5\pi/6+n\pi,\;n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $\frac1{\sin\Theta}=2$ is perfectly possible.

Comment: Wait what question is this? Im confused..

Comment: @Dsafds I gave you a way of solving both of your questions. Try to do it by your own, just in case I have done something wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. $2\cos^2\theta-3\cos\theta+1=0$:

Use the change of variables $x=\cos\theta$, in order to write the equation as
$$
2x^2-3x+1=0
$$
Solving for $x$ yields 
$$
x=1\quad or\quad x=\frac{1}{2}
$$
so in terms of $\theta$:
$$
\theta=0\quad or \quad \theta=\frac{\pi}{3}\quad or \quad \theta=-\frac{\pi}{3}
$$

2. $\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=2\cos\theta$:

Multiplying both terms by $\sin\theta$ yields
$$
\cos\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)=\sin2\theta
$$
And solving for $\theta$ gives us
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta = 2\theta +2n\pi \quad or \quad \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta = \pi- 2\theta+2n\pi,
$$
that is:
$$
\theta\in \{\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{6},\frac{3\pi}{2}\}
$$

Comment: @Kuifie may you show how you solved for x?

Comment: Don't you mean $2x^2 - 3x + 1 = 0$?

Comment: $2x^2-3x+1=0$ is a quadratic equation. Standard techniques can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: Let me try to solve it and ill notify you! Yes i do @N.F.Taussig